# How to create test server / sql server on windows azure

Tags: sql, azure, testing

We have live Virtual Machine/Sql in azure.

Now i want to create Test Virtual Machine to host asp.net application and test sql server.

Please me know :

1. How to create Test Virtual Machine to host asp.net
2. How to create test SQL server - to host test database
3. What is the cost to create VM/SQL
4. How to move from test to live

Thanks in advance,

Regards
Jagdish Kotian

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have azure subscription or free subscription

1) You can create the simple VM using Virtual Machines - > Create VM. Now you have option to choose the image windows server or windows sql server. Now cost you need to check with azure team only. If you create the windows server image then you yourself need to set up IIS and server server with your license.

2) Same for sql server but the default port for sql server is 1433 i think whereas for VM you can configure the endpoint and. So your organization might have various port blocked so change the endpoint to port 80 and try to connect vm using rdp connection.

3) I think best way is to check azure team latest billing

4) In azure there are two enviornments Staging and Production under each server. So assume the Staging as test enviornment and then once you are confident then just you need to swap the enviornment so now your staging enviorment will be production. But for VM there are lot of things like you have availability set, load balancing etc. I think first check about IAAS service offered.

Comment: Hi Mahesh, Thanks for the reply.  I have azure paid subscription.  Just i want to know any extra charges for creating staging.  Also let me know how to create staging for sql database.

Comment: Sorry for database there is no staging concept. Database you need to manage. For VM or cloud services it will create the staging and production